# Disable threaded email in Gmail app

Tags: gmail

How can I disable threaded email in the default gmail app on my s3 android.... I would like to see each individual email instead of all the threads mashed together.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment the Gmail app doesn't support normal email views, only the conversation view is available.

As a workaround I believe you can open your gmail account to [allow pop3 access](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13273), and then you can use the default email application, instead of the gmail application.